# How best to search a Javascript array for partial matches?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to Javascript and I expect there is a simple answer, but how can you search a Javascript array for a partial match?

So if I have an array such as:

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

I know I can easily check if the array contains something using:

```
fruits.includes("Mango");
```

But what if I want to know whether an array contains a value that partially matches a certain sequence of characters?

For example, if I want to know if the above array includes an entry that has the string "Man" in it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `filter` if you want to find multiple objects might match, or `find` if you only want one, or if you just want to know if it exists at all use `some`

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

const fruitsWithMan = fruits.filter(x => x.includes("Man"))
console.log(fruitsWithMan); // returns array

const oneFruitWithMan = fruits.find(x => x.includes("Man"))
console.log(oneFruitWithMan); // returns single item

const hasFruitWithMan = fruits.some(x => x.includes("Man"));
console.log(hasFruitWithMan); // return boolean
```

Comment: Why are you using `indexOf` instead of `includes`?

Comment: @LiamPillay no reason at all. `includes` is almost certainly more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array this way :

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

console.log(fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.includes("Man")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"].some(fruit => fruit.includes("Man"));
```